# Как по условию добавить XElement

Tags: c#, linq

```
var offerElement =
new XElement("offer", new XAttribute("id", reader["productID"]),
...
//вот тут должно быть условие, какой синтаксис использовать? Если true добавить элемент, в противном случае не добавлять
new XElement("url", reader["url"])  ???
...
```

Comment: `true?new XElement("url", reader["url"]):null`

Comment: условие для чего? что у вас должно быть true? Добавьте хотя бы нерабочий вариант, который вы пробовали

Comment: Дело в том что вот так мне сделать нельзя Convert.ToDouble(reader["OldPrice"]) != 0 ? new XElement("oldprice", reader["old_price"]) : null, мне нужно проигнорировать вывод XElement вообще. Трудности возникли из-за того что условие необходимо вставить в new XElement("offer", new ...

Comment: `new XElement("offer", new XAttribute("id", reader["productID"]), Convert.ToDouble(reader["OldPrice"]) != 0 ? new XElement("oldprice", reader["old_price"]) : null)`

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
var offerElement =
    new XElement("offer", new XAttribute("id", reader["productID"]));

if (условие)
    offerElement.Add(new XElement("url", reader["url"]));
```